# Item price keeps getting updated in Cart

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I would like to understand if this is phenomenon is the usual behavior in Sitecore Commerce.

At different stages in the purchase flow, the application displays the item's price and this is being fetched from the Cart (backed code I mean).

When price in the Business tools is updated manually, and the purchase page is refreshed, the price is updated there.

I was assuming that once an item is added to the Cart, the price will not changed until the transaction is complete or the Cart is abandoned.

Please confirm if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct, item price keeps updating if there is any update in price on an added item in Cart.

If you want to control this then you may need to do customization. In pipeline `IPopulateLineItemPipeline` there is a block `CalculateCartLinePriceBlock`, in this block you can add some flag from which you can control this behavior if you want to.